# IBM server x3400-7976KGJ support for VMWare ESXi 5

Tags: vmware-esxi, ibm

I searched over internet but I haven't been able to find if an IBM server x3400-7976KGJ is compatible with VMWare ESXi 5.0/5.5; I need to install a Windows Server 2012 OS on this machine and with the current ESX 4.0 I need to patch the bios as I've already done to been able to install Windows 8.

Someone has tested this server with one of these OS?

Thanks all

EDIT:
my machine has an Intel XEON E5410 @ 2.33 GHz and 16 Gb of RAM: the storage adapter is a ServeRAID 8k/8k-l8 if there are other useful specifications I can write just let me know.
I'm sorry but I cannot "just try" to install because it is a problematic environment, I've got to be sure before do the update.

Comment: To be sure of what? The ESXi installer won't install onto incompatible hardware.

Comment: @ewwhite: to be sure before buy the license needed to upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an entire compatibility guide on VMware's site:

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php

If your x3400 is the m2 or m3 it's compatible up to 5.1 u2 as shown on that site.

Comment: Partner name: IBM  Keyword: x3400  this will give you a list then you can find your CPU series.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your specifications (*which you didn't provide in your question for some reason*) You'll need an Intel 5100, 5300 or 5400-series CPU to be able to run ESXi 5.1 or greater. The key is enabling Intel VT extensions. You'll also want 4GB or more of RAM. The storage controller is likely supported, but again, details matter.

Try it for yourself.